# How to receive hover events on QGraphicsItems during drop?

Tags: qt, qt4

I use two different QGraphicView's and do drag'n'drop between them. The dragdrop does work very well so far. In one of my QGraphicView's I have items that receive hover events so that they are lighted when the mouse moves on them. The problem is that during drops and also during moves on items, the hover events won't get called. Is it possible to overcome this behaviour somehow? The hover events mark the places the drop can occur in my view and the items then have to be dropped at the right places accordingly (they can only be inserted at specific places and the user should get some feedback).

I hope I could describe my problem...I posted no code for now, because I do not know if this is even possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the graphics view framework yet, but you'll probably need to subclass QGraphicsView (if you haven't already) and override QWidget::DragEnterEvent. Depending on how you coded your objects, they might also have a DragEnterEvent that you can use.

In either case you'd accept the QDragEnterEvent and have it trigger the hover event. Hope that points you in the right direction.